# Binary tree, print out which level I am on

Tags: c, binary-tree

I want to print out into my sorted tree **on which level this number was** and that must be a **recursion** function.

Here is my code:

```
void printout(KNOTEN *start) {  
    if (start == NULL)
        return;

    printout(start->left);
    printf("%d\n", start->number);
    printout(start->right);

    free(start);
}
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
My input Numbers 41, 18467, 6334 , 26500, 19169
Outprint is 41,6334,18467,19169,26500
```

What I want is:

```
41 Level 1 , 6334 level 3 , 18467 level 2 , 26500 level 3 , 19169 level 4
```

Comment: How is the "level" related with the stack-depth of invoking the `printout` functions? What level are you the first time `printout` is invoked? How can you pass this information to the next time it is invoked?

Comment: Please don't edit away your question into uselessness.  I will revert it...

Comment: Is this because its a school assignment and you don't want the answer to be traced back to here?

Comment: Yes I dont want it. I tryied 2 hours and ask now for help and if they also coundnt do this they also can ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify it to this:

```
void printout(KNOTEN *start, int depth)
{   
    if(start == NULL)
        return;

    printout(start->left, depth+1);
    printf("%d(%d) \n",start->number, depth);
    printout(start->right, depth+1);

    free(start);
 }
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

here is a hint. your prototype is this

```
printout(KNOTEN *start, int the_level)
```

and this is how you call it to start your search.

```
printout(node, 1);
```

and there is a the_level + 1 in two places in your code.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, so I'm not going to give you complete code.  But the idea is to keep count of how many recursive calls you've made:

```
int myRecursiveFunction(Node *node, int thingToFind, int level)
{
    if (someCondition())
    {
        return level;
    }
    else
    {
        if (goLeft())
        {
            return myRecursiveFunction(node->left, thingToFind, level+1);
        }
        else
        {
            return myRecursiveFunction(node->right, thingToFind, level+1);
        }
    }
}


...

int level = myRecursiveFunction(root, thingToFind, 0);
```